# How to show an imported layer asset on screen, after zooming into a canvas area with Gimp

Tags: gimp

With Gimp 2.8.0
I'm zooming into a specific region of my canvas area that is about 400% in.  From this point, when I click create new layer (about 50px by 50px), the new layer is created at the very top left corner of my canvas (outside my zoomed area).

How can a new layer asset be fully visible within the zoomed-in canvas area of Gimp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new layer. Let it be full sized. It must be transparent.

Make a selection which covers the wanted layer area

Fill the selection with paint bucket

Goto Layer > Autocrop

press DEL to make the new layer empty, if needed

Comment: Layer->Autocrop did it for me.  Thanks for pointing that out. It's second nature after the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on @user287001's answer:

1. No need for bucket-fill+autocrop. `Layer>Crop to selection` will do it.
2. Even faster <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Shift-N</kbd> (in other words, make a new layer from the selection)

Note that in all cases the selection doesn't need to be rectangular. In practice the fastest and easiest is to make a diamond selection with a corner in the middle of each side.

Comment: thanks for the fix. But we both made the same error. Obviously the questioner paints something and wants to remove the extra layer space after it to keep the file smaller => Autocrop alone is the solution.

Comment: Then why was your answer accepted? Both answers answer the question, and in particular its title... So maybe the OQ should be edited.

Comment: the question showed the dead end of questioner's attempts, not the problem, only something that he hoped to be the solution. My answer had one useful word which gave to him an idea how to walk on.

Comment: Still, our answers are coherent with the question asked. If it's not the right question, it has to be withdrawn or formulated differently (in which case I will remove my answer).

Comment: We answered to the text, formally exactly right. I happened to remember the autocropping, you had better knowledge and will earn more upvotes.  But the questioner surely has already other things to do.

Comment: I feel both answers helped me out. I learned 2 new techniques today.  Thanks guys!